# Terraform Unknown Parameter or Attribute What is it

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm just beginning terraform.  Fortunately, I got a basic azure deployment of a resource group working.

But there is one "parameter" or attribute or something that I do not know what it means.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group.html

In the "basic" example for an azure resource group (although the question is not applies to more than just an azure-resoure-group), the syntax looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "testResourceGroup1"
  location = "West US"

  tags {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

So I totally understand "name", "location", tags.

And I understand "azurerm_resource_group"..which drives the functionality.

What is the "**test**" value?  It seems like it can be anything.

Other items have it:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html

Again the same "test" value.

What is that thing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the name you're giving your resource in the Terraform scripts - it allows you to reference it elsewhere in the script.

For example, if you want to use the [`id`](https://terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group.html#id) attribute that's exported from that resource elsewhere in your script, you would use:

```
somethingelse =    "${azurerm_resource_group.test.id}"
                                          #   ^ name used here
```

Comment: Yeah the documentation is a bit bare bones at times

Comment: Suggestion to the OP. Be careful how you choose the names: they are internal to Terraform, but if you change them (say refactoring), Terraform will destroy and recreate the resources.

Comment: Thanks @GiulioVian  Yes, I'm getting a sense of terraforms "seek and DESTROY" mission !  So now i"m very glad I asked this question earlier than later.